# What are the semantics of glRotate and glTranslate's parameters?

Tags: opengl, java, rotation, lwjgl

I have been trying to play with OpenGL after watching some tutorials and I don't understand how the `glTranslatef` and `glRotatef` functions work. I believe a simple picture would help me.

I understand that `glTranslatef` changes the position of the "camera" (but does it change the position in wich the shapes are getting drawn)?

However, I don't understand the rotation concept at all. If I do `glRotatef(1,0,0,1)` it makes my quad spin around. If I just do `glRotatef(1,0,0,0)` it makes the quad smaller (further away) but if I try to rotate around the X or Y axis, I get a black screen. I don't understand the angle either. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by others, the function families [`glRotate`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRotate.xml) and [`glTranslate`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) are deprecated, so if you have the ability to use a more modern version of OpenGL, you should.

That said, the concepts you are struggling with are not specific to those two functions, although you may be getting hampered by the fact that those functions are operating on a *matrix stack*, which is somewhat GL-specific.

In 3D graphics, when you send some geometry (vertices) to the CPU to be rendered, that geometry is transformed (on the GPU) by the current 4x4 [transformation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix). In OpenGL (and disregarding for the moment [shaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shader), which are part of the modern programmable pipeline you should eventually become aware of), the convention is to represent that matrix as two matrices: the *modelview* and the *projection* matrix. The OpenGL API allows you to manipulate both of those matrices independently on the CPU-side of the API, and they are [concatenated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_concatenation) on the GPU prior to a rendering operation.

In legacy OpenGL, where you'd use the `glRotate` and `glTranslate` functions, that CPU-side manipulation is presented to you as a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29) of individual matrices, which you push onto via the two functions you are having trouble with. When you call `glRotate` (or `glTranslate`), you specify a single transformation matrix. That matrix is then *multiplied* with whatever matrix is currently on top of the stack for the [current matrix mode](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml) and the result becomes the new top of the stack.

That's why it's usually important to use [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml) to reset the stacks when you start preparing a new frame, and that's why you can sometimes get unexpected results when you make several matrix function calls in a row, especially since (for matrix multiplication), the order of the multiplication changes the result significantly.

So then, to address your specific questions:

- When you call `glTranslate` you can choose to interpret (in your own head) whether the transform is altering the camera or the objects in the scene. Both representations are valid (although switching between them may mathematically involve switching signs or where in the code you call the function).
- When you call `glRotate` you are creating an [axis-angle rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation). Again, you are free to interpret whether this affects the "camera" or the "objects" in the world, as to the API there is no difference.
- The actual parameters to the rotation function are (in order): `angle`, `x`, `y`, and `z`. The `angle` parameter specifies the rotation amount, in degrees, and the (`x`, `y`, `z`) triple represent the components of a vector that defines the rotation axis. OpenGL will normalize the input vector if needed, and the function follows the right-hand rule, so if the vector points "towards" the screen, the rotation will be counter-clockwise.

Based on that, I'd venture to say that the unexpected behavior you are seeing appears to be because you have the parameter order confused -- in your second rotation example, you have asked to create a rotation matrix around the axis `(0, 0, 0)` which is invalid and produces a malformed matrix that does the unexpected things.

Also make sure that

- you switch matrix modes between modelview and projection accordingly (you generally will need to call `glMatrixMode` twice during scene setup, once to set up the projection part of the transform, and again to set up the modelview part.
- you reset the stack after the `glMatrixMode` call using `glLoadIdentity`.
- you perform all calls to the matrix functions *outside* the `glBegin` and `glEnd` pair if you are using them (you should work on moving away from them to modern OpenGL equivalents when you can, however).

Comment: Well , that was helpful... So , I wasted that much time for something I wont use? Omg... and now it seems that I am learning the OpenGL wrongly. I will check out what is OGL and OGL ES etc... What should I start reading to learn OpenGL properly (without having version issues , being up to date and covering the deprecated stuff?). Thanks a lot for that information. That really made me understand how things work, altough calculating it seems pretty tricky. Do you mind giving me your e-mail? I would like to ask you one or two more questions...

Comment: Sorry , wouldnt fit in one comment. One more thing , how does glTranslate work? Does it create a axis-rotation matrix or? I dont know what to assume at the time being. Also , at the main loop , I should incluse glLoadIdentity? I will stop developing till I know for sure what to study ...

Comment: I'd suggest checking out: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ If you'd like to ask follow-up questions, you can post them on this site (as separate questions please) or you can check out the [chat] for more real-time discussion or for questions that would be off-topic per the [faq].

Comment: glTranslate produces a translation matrix: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)

Comment: So , last thing , glRotate puts the camera at the x,y,z and rotates it clockwise as much as the degrees are?Working on understanding translation.

Comment: No. The (X,Y,Z) simply define a vector that will be the axis of rotation (the "line" around which the geometry will rotate). The act of "positioning the camera" must be accomplished via a translation transform (or glTranslate).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see an actual question in your post so I'm assuming it to be: What are glRotatef and glTranslatef in context of OpenGL.

Well the answer is, **deprecated**! Use another math library instead.
I would suggest glm but that is C++, maybe [jglm](https://github.com/jroyalty/jglm) is reasonable? (I wouldn't know)

FYI: glRotatef is a 4x4 matrix implementation of [Axis Angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation) rotation. Translation is straightforward read the math library documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here for the docs: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRotate.xml

glRotatef( angleInDegrees, x, y, z );

if you draw a line from 0,0,0 to x,y,z this will give you the axis which you will be rotating about.  the angle defines how much you want to rotate about this axis.

make sure you are handling your model view matrix with push/pop or resetting to identity in each frame so that you can make sense of how this works, otherwise you'll be compounding the rotation with with frame and you may not be able to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Does in put the "camera" at x-y-z coordinates and then rotate or it just makes it face that direction and then rotate?